# A single prepared statement placeholder is not working

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following code on one server. It works fine.

```
$developer_id = $_SESSION['auth']['id'];

$sql = "select sum(file_size) as total_storage_size, (select count(*) from language_set where developer_id = :DEVELOPER_ID) as total_projects, (select count(*) from testing_group where developer_id = :DEVELOPER_ID) as total_test_apps, (select count(*) from published_group where developer_id = :DEVELOPER_ID) as total_published_apps, account_type from resource JOIN language_set on resource.set_id = language_set.id JOIN developer on developer_id = developer.id where developer_id = :DEVELOPER_ID";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":DEVELOPER_ID", $developer_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$account_info = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

However, when I move it to another server it gives incorrect results. For example, it gives account_type as "NULL" instead of "standard".

I have tracked down the problem to the following issues:

- the $developer_id when pulled from the database becomes a string. If I cast it to an int it works fine.
- It is only the last :DEVELOPER_ID in the sql statement that is giving a problem, the other :DEVELOPER_IDs have no problem accepting the string value

**Here are my questions:**

1. Why does it work fine on a server running PHP 5.6 but not on my new server running PHP 7.0
2. Why is it only the last :DEVELOPER_ID that is an issue and not the first three?

Comment: Is `developer_id` stored as the correct type for all tables? This could potentially have an effect on your results. Additionally, on executing your query an integer value will be changed to string. Check out `Steve M`'s post on the PHP documentation here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php My recommendation is to cast the `$developer_id` to an int when applying to the session to simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

Type casting is more essential in PHP7.

In PHP5 you could do:

$a = "9";
print( 9 * $a);

In PHP7:

$a = "9";
print( 9 * (int) $a);